# @Autowired springboot object is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I always used spring boot in web developement in a prodution context, I hazardly was playing in my free time so I thouth about some DI training, I tried to inject a component in the main class but I m surprised that is not working using bean injection, Why ??

here is my small code

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExposéApplication {

        @Autowired
        private static Joeur ikram;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExposéApplication.class, args);
                System.out.println(ikram);
    }


        @Bean
        public Joeur createjoueur(){
            System.out.println("bean created");
            return new Joeur("ikram");
        }
}
```

Comment: Hover over the downvote button to learn what their purpose is.

Comment: You can't autowire to static fields.